# Get first HTML-element in QueryPath using find

Tags: php, find, css-selectors, querypath

I am trying to retreive one specific element from HTML-code using QueryPath. It occurs twice, I only want the first one though. 
Searching for the object DOES work, but it returns me two elements.
I was trying to add a pseudo-class-selector to my search, but that didn't work.

This is the HTML-element that occurs twice in the code:

```
<span class="aui-suffix"> of 5 </span>
```

And this is how I am searching for it:

```
$arrURL = "URL..."

$html = htmlqp( $arrURL );
$pageAsString = $html->find('span.aui-suffix');
echo $pageAsString->text();
```

The output is "of 5 of 5 ", which is both elements printed right after each other.
How can I modify my search to get me only "of 5 "?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try
`$pageAsString = $html->find('span.aui-suffix:eq(0)');`

Comment: That makes $pageAsString go empty, it does not return anything at all

Comment: Just found it while looking for something else. It goes as following:

    $pageAsString = $html->find('span.aui-suffix')->eq(0);

Couldn't post the answer myself because my reputation isn't high enough yet

Comment: glad you found the solution, i knew it would be something along those lines. the one i used `span.aui-suffix:eq(0)` is more like a js/jquery selector